# modifying a function to apply class in correct place

Tags: jquery

With the following function:

```
function calculateLIsInRow() {
  var lisInRow = 0;
  $('.mobileversionworkflow ul li span:first-child').each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("back");
    if ($(this).prev().length > 0) {
      if ($(this).position().top != $(this).prev().position().top) {
        $('.mobileversionworkflow ul li span:first-child').prev().addClass("back");
        //return false;
      }
      lisInRow++;
    } else {
      lisInRow++;
    }
    if ($(this).next().length > 0) {} else {
      $(this).addClass("back");
    }
  });
}
calculateLIsInRow();
```

here is the issue, the li has the class as "back", i want to apply the class to the span after the class `border_process` like `border_process back`

```
<li class="back"> <span class="border_process"></span>
                                 <span class="process_workflow_box">
                                 <span class="process_workflow_box_im">
                                 <img src="images/c2.png" alt="">
                                 </span>
                                 <span class="process_workflow_txt">
                                 discovery <br>&amp; research
                                 </span>
                                 </span>
                              </li>
```

where i want to apply it on the following

```
<li> <span class="border_process back"></span>
                                     <span class="process_workflow_box">
                                     <span class="process_workflow_box_im">
                                     <img src="images/c2.png" alt="">
                                     </span>
                                     <span class="process_workflow_txt">
                                     discovery <br>&amp; research
                                     </span>
                                     </span>
                                  </li>
```

Comment: Surely you just need to change `$(this).addClass("back");` to `$(this).find('span').first().addClass("back");`  to target the `span`, not the `li` which is in context?

Comment: this seems to be applying the chnage only to the last li's span

Answer (score 0):

```js
function calculateLIsInRow() {
  var lisInRow = 0;
  $('li span:first-child').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("back");
    if ($(this).prev().length > 0) {
      if ($(this).position().top != $(this).prev().position().top) {
        $('li span:first-child').prev().addClass("back");
        //return false;
      }
      lisInRow++;
    } else {
      lisInRow++;
    }
    if ($(this).next().length > 0) {} else {
      $(this).addClass("back");
    }
  });
}
calculateLIsInRow();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="back"> <span class="border_process"></span>
                                 <span class="process_workflow_box">
                                 <span class="process_workflow_box_im">
                                 <img src="images/c2.png" alt="">
                                 </span>
                                 <span class="process_workflow_txt">
                                 discovery <br>&amp; research
                                 </span>
                                 </span>
                              </li>
```

It seems i am able to add class back to spans. Hope it helps

Comment: yes, it seems working, but it is apply the class "back" to internal span too. & it is applying the css to every li's first span where it should only apply to the last li near to screen, like mobile on the right hand side, like if i check in mobile, it should be the every second li of the UL

Comment: For that change the selector as something 'li:last-child span:first-child'. It should work that way. Its all about selectors.

Comment: i changed something but now it is pointing to the every second li (by far which comes nearest to the right side of the device) it encounters but it should do to the first span of that li, my code is here in the pastebin

https://pastebin.com/ccxKVwZy